# Vue v-html : stop executing script inside a iframe rendered

Tags: iframe, vue.js

In vue, v-html won't execute script tags. But if we place a iframe as the html, and the iframe source is having a script, then it will be executed. Is there anyway we can stop this?

Comment: your question would be very helpful for other if you share your code where code in iframe is executing ?

Comment: as an example, if the iframe is loading a page which contains
<script> alert('a') </script> the script will be displayed in the browser. Is there anyway i can block the scripts inside